# Google Forms w/ jQuery Validate Not Submitting to Form in IE 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate

In IE7, when a user fills out this Google Form w/ jq validate.js, and clicks the Submit button, the page navigates to the "success" page, but our form isn't showing the submitted content.

http://www.xtracycle.com/lifetime-freeradical-warranty-and-guarantee/

I read that IE 7 has issues with input elements having both a type and class/id/name of "submit", but when I try and change the button input's name, the Google js no longer submits the form content in FF or on my Mac.

Thanks for any insight into what issues IE 7 has with jq validate and Google Forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually not using an input field for your submit button, it is a button object. Internet Explorer treats button objects a bit different from other browsers. This w3schools page addresses some of the issue.

[HTML Button Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

If you instead use an input field with a type of submit you will likely have less compatibility problems.

Comment: Crazy, a button form is on our registration page and that's submitting fine: http://www.xtracycle.com/warranty-registration/

But, did the change you suggested and the other form is working. Thank you very much, Joe!